# Time complexity modified bubblesort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

Have this java code for bubblesort:

```
public void sort() {
    for(int i = 1; i < getElementCount() ; ++i) {
        for(int j = getElementCount()-1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (cmp(j,j-1) < 0) swap(j, j-1);
        }
    }
}
```

the method "cmp" and "swap" are as follows:

```
public int cmp(int i, int j) {
    return get(i).intValue()-get(j).intValue();
}

public void swap(int i, int j) {
    Integer tmp = get(i);
    set(i, get(j));
    set(j, tmp);
}
```

I have now written an improved version of the Bubblesort where the sorting method "sort()" looks like this:

```
public void sort() {
    boolean done = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < getElementCount() && !done; ++i) {
        done = true;
        for(int j = getElementCount()-1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (cmp(j,j-1) < 0) {
                swap(j, j-1);
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how to compute the time complexity of the latter algorithm? I'm thinking it's comparing n elements one time, and therefore it has complexity O(1) in its best case, and O(n^2) in it's worst case scenario, but I don't know if I'm right and would like to know how to think on this issue.

Comment: If it's comparing N elements one time in its best case, the time complexity would be O(N) since the number of comparisons depend on the number of elements. Regarding its worst case, as you said it's O(N^2).

Comment: How's that different than "regular" bubble sort?!?

Comment: Hi Giovanni. If the array is sorted in increasing order, and I'm using bubble sort (as described above) then it still has to run through every element to check that they're all sorted. Meanwhile in the improved version, it just runs through the array once and - since it's sorted - it's done there and doesn't have to run through the entire array as the un-improved bubble sort does. I hope that makes sense..

Comment: If you have one loop inside another both looking at all elements one at a time it is O(n^2)

Comment: Do you mean it is O(n^2) for both the best and the worst case?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity tells the programmer how long time it takes to process the data.

The O(1) complexity says that no matter how many elements it will only take one operation.

Insert a value in an array would have O(1)

E.g.

```
array[100] = value;
```

In your best case you will have to loop throught the entire array and compare each element.
Your complexity code is then O(n) where n is number of elements in the array.
In the worst case you will have to run through the array once for each element, that would give a complexity of O(n*n)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm wondering: How come the improved bubblesort is more efficient then, if the best and worst case for the both algorithms are the same? (since the Internet says that the best and worst case for Bubblesort are O(n) and O(n^2))

Comment: Not quite.  O(1) means that in the worst case the number of steps necessary does not depend on the value n.  The actual number may be very large (which is why algorithms with larger complexity can beat those with smaller for small datasets - their constant are so much smaller that it offsets the difference in complexity)

Answer (score 0):

I just looked over what you've done and it is exactly the same as the one you had previously listed. You have set a boolean condition done = false and then you are checking the negation of it which will always evaluate to true - exactly the same logic as before. You can remove done in your code and you will see that it runs exactly the same. Just like before, you will have a best case complexity of O(n) and a worst case complexity of O(n^2). There is no way any sorting algorithm is O(1) as at the very least you at least have to move through the list once which gives O(n).

Comment: The difference is that it doesn't even go into the first for-loop because of the "!done". And yes, if I remove the boolean, it is exactly the same, but with the boolean it gets marked as "done sorting" faster than the first algorithm since the first one has to compare every element before it gets marked as done.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say but it is redundant. In every nth iteration in Bubble Sort, the nth smallest (or biggest depending on how you are sorting) element would have 'bubbled' to the top nth position (and hence the name). The condition that you are trying to check is already satisfied by the nature of the algorithm.

Comment: Also, besides that, you are setting done = false at the end of the inner loop as a result of which done remains false when the outer loop begins to execute (just like the very first time) which resolves to the same thing.

Comment: If I have an array that is entirely sorted though, and then run the both algorithms at the same time, the improved bubblesort-algorithm get's marked as "done" much much faster than the regular bubblesort. I don't really understand why the condition is redundant in that case, please explain

Comment: The reason is because you are resetting done = false in the inner loop . Now when the time the outer loop starts again, done = false -> exactly the same as it was when the loop started the first time and this keeps going to the end. You could try this by placing break points in both methods and seeing how many times the loops get executed. You will find they are exactly the same. Also note that, while considering complexities we assume, n rises to infinity -> one or two tep reductions do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Worst Case : If the array is sorted in the sorted reverse order (descending) , it will show the worst time complexity of O(N^2).

Best Case : If the array is in sorted order, then the inner loop will go through each element at least once so it is O(N) - > (If you break out of the loop using the information in done, which is not present in the code).

At no point can it be a O(1) (In fact it is mathematically impossible to get a lower function than O(N) as the lower bounds for sorting is Omega(N) for comparison based sorts)

Omega(N) is the lowest possible function, as for comparison you have to see all elements at least once.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to represent your loops using Sigma notation like the following (General Case):

[image]

'c' here refers to the constant time of `if`, `cmp`, and `swap` that execute inside the innermost loop.

For the best case (modified bubble sort), the running time should look like this:

[image]